# Push Sales Orders to the API Consumers (iOS, Android, Javascript) via REST Api

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, nancy

`REST Api` is being developed using `Nancy Framework` for `C#`. Customers places the Sales Order via `POST` endpoint, it gets saved into the `database`.

The new and updated Orders information should be posted via `REST Api` to the subscribers. The subscribers could be using `Android, iOS` or Web applications (built using `Java script`).

I am not sure what should be the approach, I've browsed through the Internet, but couldn't get much help. I was also looking into `Firebase`, can some one please point me to the right topic.

Comment: As i understood you correctly you want to push from server to mobile? If yes look to "push notification" this is the was how you can push data to mobile phone.

Comment: I need to display the order header such as Customer Name, Ordered from, Order Amount, Date, Time, etc and that can be displayed in a list view by iOS, Android or Web.

Comment: But then you should have one more method in Nancy framework which returns that kind of data.

Comment: Sure, having a new method is not a problem. The data should be pushed from Server to the Client when the change (add or update) is detected to the Order.

Comment: Then you need to look to push notification. THis is when lets say user submited order, and close app, there is some jobs on server and as soon order status is changed you will be able to push from server to mobile that specific order is processed. https://www.urbanairship.com/push-notifications-explained Push notifications are usefull that even app is closed you are able to communicate with mobile device.

Comment: Hav look at https://youtu.be/m2txoLvosVw it explains how to use PushSharp to send out pushnotifications, It would play nicely together with nancy I think. Only thing is it was mentioned that on iOS your App doesn't get the Notification if it's in the background unless the user tapps on it,
So mybe you are better off polling the state of your order from time to time,

Comment: After I posted this question, I have been reading quite a lot about Firebase database. I have a feeling it can be solved using Firebase approach. Am I making sense. I will watch the YouTube, thnaks

Comment: Firebase also has good hooks for android, iOS and JavaScript frameworks.